# R error z[seq_len(nro), ] <- y : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, json, api

Hope you are fine. I am experimenting connecting API to R to extract data. I would like to combine both data frames however I am getting this error:

`z[seq_len(nro), ] <- y :    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

I just want to combine both results in 1 data frame.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

# ---- the first dataframe

MY_ACCUWEATHER_KEY<-'wtRsZMNpRYeGdjf97eQHNGh6SsiWUHAs'
location='113006'
base_url<- 'http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/'
url.query<-paste0(base_url,location)

# this is to get the information from the json from the url
my_raw_result<-httr::GET(url.query, query=list(apikey=MY_ACCUWEATHER_KEY))
myparsed.content<-content(my_raw_result,as='text')
json.content<-fromJSON(myparsed.content)
forecast_df<- json.content$DailyForecasts

# to get the information as dataframe 
glimpse(forecast_df)
View(forecast_df)

is.data.frame(forecast_df) # TRUE

str(forecast_df) # dataframe 
View(forecast_df) # 21 columns

# ------ the second dataframe

location = '113005'
url.query<-paste0(base_url,location)

my_raw_result<-httr::GET(url.query, query=list(locationKey=location,apikey=MY_ACCUWEATHER_KEY))

myparsed.content<-content(my_raw_result,as='text')
json.content<-fromJSON(myparsed.content)
forecast_df2<- json.content$DailyForecasts

str(forecast_df2)

is.data.frame(forecast_df2) # TRUE 
View(forecast_df2) #21 columns 

# combination zone

rbind(forecast_df, forecast_df2) # error z[seq_len(nro), ] <- y :    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
forecast_df[nrow(forecast_df) + 1,] = forecast_df2 # error z[seq_len(nro), ] <- y :    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I find no reference to `nro` (not `nrow`) in your code nor in `rbind*` functions, is that a typo?

Comment: Regardless, `forecast_df` and `_df2` are not "simple" frames, most of the columns are nested frames, so `rbind`-ing seems unlikely to work well. Work on flattening your frames so that the columns are "simple" vectors and go again.

Comment: My guess is you are trying to pull the temp, day and night data frames from the two different nested frames. Either way, it's a guess, please make this clear in your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

An "easy" fix would be using `dplyr::bind_rows()`

```
new_df <- forecast_df %>% dplyr::bind_rows(forecast_df2)
```